# How can I insert a record with a specific identity using Linq with IDENTITY_INSERT set to ON

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-sql, identity-insert

I'm trying to synchronize a table between two databases using linq.  I want the primary keys (identities) in both tables to be the same.  I haven't been able to accomplish this using linq.

After scouring google, the closest I can get is this:

```
Using DbContext as New DBContext()
    'Somewhere I read that the line below ensures queries run in the same session
    DbContext.Connection.Open() 

    Dim CopyOfShoe as New Shoe()
    CopyOfShoe.ID = OriginalShoe.ID
    CopyOfShoe.Color = OriginalShoe.Color

    DbContext.ExecuteCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Shoes ON")
    DbContext.Shoes.InsertOnSubmit(CopyOfShoe)
    DbContext.SubmitChanges()
    DbContext.ExecuteCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Shoes OFF")
End Using
```

But this throws an exception:

> Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'Shoes' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

I know that I can get around this by using ExecuteCommand to insert the new record with the existing Identity, but I want to know if it is possible using just linq.